# Show warnings screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage which is designed to view using a minimum resolution of 800px width. 
I would like to add a warning to the users browsing with a resolution < 800px saying something like

> This webpage was designed to be viewed using a resolution of....

How can I do that? Is that not possible to do with CSS Media-Queries?

Comment: Instead of effectively excluding browsers and low screen resolutions, look at responsive web design, or use scalable % widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for that:

```
.resolution-warning {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .resolution-warning {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

And put in HTML somewhere:

```
<div class="resolution-warning">You screen resolution is too small.</div>
```

Here is a [**demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/0okosxt8/) and [**2**](http://jsfiddle.net/0okosxt8/1/), try resizing a browser.

Answer (score 5):

A different solution, without placing that text as an actual content into the document, is to use a pseudoelement.

e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejlsp

CSS code

```
@media all and (max-width: 799px) {

    body:before {
      content: "this webpage is best viewed...";
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 2px #ccc solid;
      outline: 400px solid rgba(20,20,20, .7);
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Good idea to use pseudo elements if one wants to show just text! For HTML formatting will still need one more tag.

Comment: Try using transform: translate(-50%, -50%) instead of the 3d version, it creates blurred texts on chrome :(